# Определить, какие ключевые слова языка Java содержит файл

Tags: java, строки, java-ee, arraylist

Нагуглил только `contains`, но он почему-то не работает.. видимо делаю что-то не так

```
keyWords - ArrayList<String>
```

`sortingList` тоже, я так понимаю нужно каким-то образом сравнить все слова в файле со списком моих слов, а как чет не доходит

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (sortingList.get(index).contains(keyWords.get(i))) {
        counter++;              
    }
}
```

Ответ ниже помог, но теперь проблема с повторяющимися словами. они не учитываются

```
for (String st : keyWords) {
                for (String g : sortingList) {
                    if (st.contains(g) && g.length() > 1) {

                        sortedList.add(g);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: А ключевые слова внутри комментариев и строковых констант считаются? Если нет, вам нужно писать честный парсер :)

Comment: @VladD Вот собственно задание: 'Прочитайте файл, содержащий код на языке Java. Определите, какие ключевые слова языка Java это код содержит. Выведите эти слова и их количество в другой файл.'

Comment: То, что это учебное задание, в лучшем случае не добавляет никакой новой информации. Если ваш преподаватель плохо его сформулировал, это ваша работа уточнить его. Если мы говорим не о «подстроках, выглядящих как ключевые слова», а о «ключевых словах в смысле синтаксиса Java», то ваше задание включает в себя настоящий парсер, и достаточно сложно.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если честно я не совсем понял вопроса. Вы хотите в увеличивать counter за каждое совпадение слов? Если да, то лучше воспользоваться циклом for-each и сделать вот так.

```
for (String s : keyWords) {
    for (String g :  sortingList) { 
        if (s.contains(g)) { 
            counter++;
        }
    }       
}
```